# text color passes to recycled list items in my adapter

Tags: android, android-listview, textview, simplecursoradapter

I'm trying to change the text colour of a textview inside a listitem if the text is a number under 5. But when i scroll up / down, the colours apply to recycled items. I've looked around and i don't really understand how these recycled items work.

Fragment Class

```
ListAdapter adapter = new RacesAdapter(getActivity(), racesList,
            R.layout.list_item,
            new String[] { TAG_NAME, TAG_GOAL, TAG_NUMENTRANTS }, new int[] {
                    R.id.gameLabel, R.id.goalLabel, R.id.entrantsLabel});
    setListAdapter(adapter);
```

RacesAdapter Class (is a modified SimpleAdapter) **(Look in bindView() for my code)**

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    return createViewFromResource(position, convertView, parent, mResource);
}

private View createViewFromResource(int position, View convertView,
        ViewGroup parent, int resource) {

    View v;
    if (convertView == null) {
        v = mInflater.inflate(resource, parent, false);
    } else {
        v = convertView;
    }

    bindView(position, v);
    return v;
}

public void setDropDownViewResource(int resource) {
    this.mDropDownResource = resource;
}

@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    return createViewFromResource(position, convertView, parent, mDropDownResource);
}

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
private void bindView(int position, View view) {
    final Map dataSet = mData.get(position);
    if (dataSet == null) {
        return;
    }

    final String[] from = mFrom;
    final int[] to = mTo;
    final int len = to.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        final View v = view.findViewById(to[i]);
        if (v != null) {


            final Object data = dataSet.get(from[i]);
            String text = data == null ? "" : data.toString();
            if (text == null) {
                text = "";
            }


            boolean bound = false;
            if (mViewBinder != null) {
                bound = mViewBinder.setViewValue(v, data, text);
            }



            if (!bound) {
                if (v instanceof TextView) {
                    if(v.getId()==R.id.entrantsLabel){
                        if(Integer.parseInt(text) < 5){((TextView) v).setTextColor(Color.RED);}
                    }
                    setViewText((TextView) v, text);
                } 
                else if (v instanceof ImageView) {
                    if (data instanceof Integer) {
                        setViewImage((ImageView) v, (Integer) data);                            
                    } else {
                        setViewImage((ImageView) v, text);
                    }
                } else {
                    throw new IllegalStateException(v.getClass().getName() + " is not a " +
                            " view that can be bounds by this SimpleAdapter");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


public ViewBinder getViewBinder() {
    return mViewBinder;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you should do is, in `bindView()`, set your text color to a default. Then, it may or may not change to `Color.RED`. If it does, it's red, otherwise, it's default.

So, something like this:

```
private void bindView(int position, View view) {
    // ...

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        final View v = view.findViewById(to[i]);
        if (v != null) {

            v.setTextColor(Color.BLACK); // For example
            // ...

            if (!bound) {
                if (v instanceof TextView) {
                    if(v.getId()==R.id.entrantsLabel){
                        if(Integer.parseInt(text) < 5){((TextView) v).setTextColor(Color.RED);}
                    }
                    // ...
                } 
                // ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: that worked perfectly. thanks very much. could you explain why they change to red when a default isn't set?

Comment: They don't change; they're recycled. So, you set that view to red once, then didn't change it after it was recycled, so it just stayed red. Hence, you have to reset the color to black (or whatever default you want) in order for it to be restored properly.